# My new external HDD is generating clicking noise and vibration, is that normal?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I just bought 2 new 3.5" external HDDs STEL10000400 and STEL6000200 and noticed that there is a clicking sound on both while copying files to my drive and if i touched the HDD or even the table that i put the HDD over it i feel a vibrations when the drive do those clicks.
I recoreded and uploaded that noise/clicks sound to this link (noise in HDD_Noise_1.mp3 is more noticable)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pVl0rhxrnkrrEDsrDyFxL0Pg4slwjIoq

Also However my room tempreture is between 24-28c but my HDD runs too hot it even reached 64c and now the SMART HDD monitoring apps gives me a failure warning due to (BE) Airflow Temerature parameter as shown on the attached screenshots.

So i was wondering if that's normal or i should replace them?

Thanks

Comment: get a refund and buy a different model or brand.

Comment: Truly not normal. Get it replaced immediately.

Comment: "the SMART HDD monitoring apps gives me a failure warning due to (BE) Airflow Temerature parameter" that is not normal. Return them under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical hard drives generally do make some sound when there is intensive operation like searching or copying of large data. The sound is more of the spin rather than click.

The click sounds like mechanical faults.

**Possible causes**

- Manufacturing defect.
- May have experienced some shock (like being dropped)

Temperature unlikely to have affected it.

In the past I have had similar click sound problem but for really old hard disk (10+ years stored in the shelf). But since you got these brand new, you should get it replaced.